# Clear fields only after a successful submission of jsp page

Tags: javascript, jsp

I'm developing a change password page using jsp servlets. I want to retain values of the text boxes when wrong submissions(click submit button with wrong username and password values) are done. So I include following JavaScript and it's working. Then I need to clear all the fields when a successful submission is done. I have tried several methods but didn't success. Could anyone help me?

```
 <script>

        document.getElementById("terminalUserName").value = "${param.terminalUserName}";
        document.getElementById("currentPassword").value = "${param.currentPassword}";
        document.getElementById("newPassword").value = "${param.newPassword}";
        document.getElementById("confirmPassword").value = "${param.confirmPassword}";

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

On successful submission, reset the value

```
document.getElementById('terminalUserName').value = "";
```

Comment: If I put that code for the onclick attribute of the submit button, every time I click the submit button, the field get cleared. And also the field get cleared before submission. So it's submitting null values. But what I want is clear the fields only after a submission with correct username and password.

Comment: @thilinachathuranga you should not reset it on onclick method, instead when you get a success response (200 OK)